# How to pass Views contextual filter via URL?

Tags: views

I want to pass some values to my view via contextual filters in the URL. What GET naImes do I use? There seem to be no clue given, just this "The contextual filter values is provided by the URL".

If I have to construct that URL, how do I find out what GET var names do I need to pass so they are recognized?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Contextual filters aren't passed in separate variables, they are part of the path. If your view path is xxx/yyy then to have a filter value of nn the path would be xxx/yyy/nn.

Comment: +1. and this xxx/yyy order is the same as you can see under "Contextual filters" pane in the Views UI.

Answer (score 12):

Use Provide default value in the contextual filter.

[image: contextual filter]

also you can use php code for getting the value from url

[image]

Comment: Do you have some example of the PHP code one could use? Thanks!

Comment: It's related to that field. For example:- Is this a number field then -- return 1; or return $user->uid; etc..... will work.

Comment: Arent these options for when the value is not in the url? How will it gauge its a value sent as a parameter?

Comment: It is never a good practise to have PHP code in your database, always do your code in files and save them in a code revision system

Answer (score 6):

If you want to pass arguments via GET in the URL you can use [BEF](https://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module for this.

For example: `mydomain.com/your-view-path?field_a=valuea&field_b=valueb`

With Better Exposed Filters you need to add exposed filters (not contextual filter), check the expose this filter option and the GET variable name is below in more options. Then if you don't want to show the filter you can hide it in Better Exposed Filters Settings.

Don’t forget to enable Use Ajax option if your view is a block display.

The exposed filter style setting must be set on Better Exposed Filters instead of Basic.

It is very useful with view blocks.