# Views page showing a user's content

Tags: views

I have created a image gallery on Drupal 7 users' profiles, which I would like to present as a separate page, linked to their profiles using views.

so, there would be a page at mysite.com/typical-user/gallery

I am at a loss on how to use the contextual filters to achieve this.

Comment: I think [this is a similar question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65525/how-to-pass-views-contextual-filter-via-url), and you may want to install Advanced Help module to read more. Is there any specific question you wish to ask?

Comment: I am creating a site, and trying to have it so there are profile pages containing a menu pointing to profile/blog, profile/gallery, etc. Just like on Facebook profile pages. I assume that the pages will be views.

Comment: Did you mean to have URLs like example.com/user/XYZ/gallery or something else ?

Comment: Yes. I don't want the word "user" in the URL, which Drupal places by default. So, example.com/ayesh/gallery. I am told this cannot be done with contextual filters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter gallery images by user id try "provide default value" and than use arg(1) which is user id in your URL, More on this here : http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7

Comment: I can't seem to find where I enter that information. I can create a page at the URL saying "gallery", but nothing is populating it.