# Render a map with multiple markers from search results in GetLocations

Tags: views

I have a simple view that uses "Filter criteria" to display nodes of a specific content type filtered by whatever the user types - that's all good and working.

My issue is that every nodes has a GetLocations field that stores an address, and I'm trying to output a map that includes all the markers of the results at the top of the page.

I think I need to have a separate view that loads all the nodes found in the search view and prints the map, but I couldn't get it to work using Contextual Filters.

Any hint?

Comment: I've ended up using Better Exposed Filters http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/90109/46736