# Pass views filter from URL

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, views

How do you pass a filter value by url in drupal 8?

On my [website](https://codedesign.be/schouteten/realisaties) I have a view with a select to filter the results. This result is based on taxonomy term.

I have 4 options, All, badkamerrenovatie, elektriciteit and verwarming.

How can I set the filter by url so that I directly have a filtered list if people click on a link related to the taxonomy term. For example if people are on page elektriciteit and click trough to realisatie they see the filtered list and don't have to choose from the select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using Contextual Filters under Advanced Settings of View Edit Page. You can add URL parameters as filters in it. [This link will help you in detail](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65525/how-to-pass-views-contextual-filter-via-url)

Thanks

Comment: Ok. What url structure I need to use then when the filter is set to get the correct result? for ex. /realisaties?badkamerrenovatie or /realisaties%badkamerrenovatie ...

Comment: This link will help you how to pass url parameters: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/65525/how-to-pass-views-contextual-filter-via-url